# Drag&Drop contents between jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-tabs

Am using jquery ui tabs, I have three tabs, when i drag content from tab1 & place it over tab2 label, it should drop inside tab2 ul element, but it's not working. When I console.log ui.draggable, it showing the same tab elements, but i want dropping tab elements. Here is my code.

```
<div id="idea-field-form">
   <div id="**idea-tabs**">
      <ul class="headerBackground">
         <li class="droppabletab"><a href="#tabs-1">super_admin</a></li>
         <li class="droppabletab"><a href="#tabs-2">super_admin</a></li>
         <li class="droppabletab"><a href="#tabs-3">super_admin</a></li>         
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1" class="ideaScrollable">
         <div class="sortable_tabs">
            <ul **class="element"**>
               <li class="showfields">
                  <h4 class="header-title header-background ">Text Box</h4>                  
               </li>               
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2" class="ideaScrollable">
         <div class="sortable_tabs">
            <ul class="element">
               <li class="showfields">
                  <h4 class="header-title header-background ">Text Box 1</h4>                  
               </li>               
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3" class="ideaScrollable">
         <div class="sortable_tabs">
            <ul class="element">
               <li class="showfields">
                  <h4 class="header-title header-background ">Text Box 2</h4>                  
               </li>               
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>      
   </div>
</div>

$("#idea-tabs").tabs();
$('.element').children().draggable({
  appendTo: 'body',
  opacity: 0.9,
  helper: 'clone'
});

$('#idea-tabs').children().droppable({
  activeClass: 'ui-state-active',
  accept: '.showfields',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log '>>>',ui.draggable
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    $('#idea-tabs').tabs('option', '', $(event.target).index());
    $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(ui.draggable.draggable('instance'));
  }
});
```

I refer this from http://jsfiddle.net/mcAndry/h7raxjyu/4/

Answer (score 1):

Change the `drop` event to `append` the dragged item (`ui.draggable[0]`) to the droppable:

```
$('.elements').droppable({
  accept: '.element',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  activeClass: "can-drop",
  hoverClass: "drop-here",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable[0]);
  }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/h7raxjyu/25/)**

Comment: Dude, that's brilliant :)